# Making a method available to all models

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

```
Rails 4.2.1
Ruby 2.1.5
```

In app/models/conerns/extras.rb, I have the following:

```
module Extras
  extend ActiveSupport::Concern

  def add_slug_to_self (slug_elements = '')
    return slug_elements if !slug_elements.kind_of?(Array)
    slug_base = ''
    slug_elements.each do |se|
      slug_base = slug_base + se.to_s.upcase
    end
    self.slug = Digest::SHA256.hexdigest slug_base
  end

end
```

To use it from any of my models, I include extras.rb, and then call it from that particular model.

Is there a way I can do this, without having to explicitly include the file in every model?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
module Extras
  extend ActiveSupport::Concern

  def add_slug_to_self (slug_elements = '')
    return slug_elements if !slug_elements.kind_of?(Array)
    slug_base = ''
    slug_elements.each do |se|
      slug_base = slug_base + se.to_s.upcase
    end
    self.slug = Digest::SHA256.hexdigest slug_base
  end

end
ActiveRecord::Base.send(:include, Extras)
```

and then create a `base_extensions.rb` file in `config/initializers`, and add the folloing line:

```
require "extras"
```

Comment: This should make it available to all models, controllers and helpers? and U can also delete the extend ActiveSupport::Concern line as well?

Comment: no just model, because for controller, you need to extend `ActionController::Base`

Comment: I edited my comment while you were answering. Is the line extend ActiveSupport::Concern needed?

Comment: yes you still need it, basically what `extend ActiveSupport::Concern` is making your life much easier when you do your extension. read this page here: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/Concern.html

Comment: of course you can remove `extend ActiveSupport::Concern`, and just do it by yourself using the pure ruby way

Comment: If u find it helps please accept my solution or if there is problem let me know

Answer (score 0):

Yes, as long as you definitely want it on all models, you could define the method as part of `ActiveRecord::Base` given thats what Rails 4 models inherit from by default.

Answer (score 0):

Create a class with your code that will be inherited by any of your other classes that require the functionality. This assumes that all of the classes that will use the functionality inherit from ActiveRecord::Base.

**First create your Extra class:**

```
class Extra < ActiveRecord::Base
  def add_slug_to_self (slug_elements = '')
    return slug_elements if !slug_elements.kind_of?(Array)
    slug_base = ''
    slug_elements.each do |se|
    slug_base = slug_base + se.to_s.upcase
  end
  self.slug = Digest::SHA256.hexdigest slug_base
end
```

end

**Then have the classes that require the functionality inherit the class:**

```
class SampleClass < Extra
  ...
end
```